# Join by two slightly different keys in Pig

Tags: string, join, merge, mapreduce, apache-pig

A mapreduce task:

Key1 in file_one is a1,a2,a3,a10,a11,a12; 
Key2 in file_two is persona1, persona1, persona2, persona3, persona12,persona12,persona3, persona11, persona10.

Merge_file=JOIN file_one BY Key1, file_two by Key2??(how to write this..)

And since the second key has duplication, does it matter?

thanks

Comment: What would the additional fields match against? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a new column for each dataset and join on that, eg.:

```
A = foreach file_one generate *, join_key1 as SUBSTRING(key1, 1, 100);
B = foreach file_two generate *, join_key2 as SUBSTRING(key2, 7, 100);
C = join A by join_key1, B by join_key2;
```